# Facebook-API: how to set "option" instead of "setting/value" when writing settings for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**TLDR** 
i try to change a setting for one of my facebook-pages by API.
The Syntax has changed but i can not figure out how.

**whole story**

The example code from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/settings) is:

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{page-id}/settings',
  array (
    'setting' => 'USERS_CAN_POST_VIDEOS',
    'value' => false,
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

if i try that i get the following exception:

```
(#12) 'setting' is deprecated for versions v2.2 and higher
```

Which seems to be noted in the changelog [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

But i can not figure out the new syntax. When i try the following:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{page-id}/settings',
  array (
    'option' => array(
            'USERS_CAN_POST' => true
        )
  )
);
```

i get this error:

```
OAuthException (#100) option requires exactly one key"
```

And with this syntax:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{page-id}/settings',
  array (
        'USERS_CAN_POST' => true
    )
);
```

Error this time:

```
(#100) Requires exactly one and only one of the params: option,setting
```

**So which is the correct syntax to set an option now?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/428676620628763/) with facebook and got a reply after 30 minutes(!). This is the needed format:

```
array (
        'option' => '{APPEARS_IN_RELATED_PAGES:true}'
)
```